# How to "require" text files with browserify?

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, commonjs, browserify

I am using browserify (using browserify-middleware)
how can I require simple text files, something like:

```
var myTmpl = require("myTmpl.txt");
```

I cheked [stringify](https://github.com/JohnPostlethwait/stringify) plugin for browserify but the code in the documentation is not working with browserify V2

Answer (score 44):

`require()` is really best for just javascript code and json files to maintain parity with node and to improve readability of your code to outsiders who expect `require()` to work the way it does in node.

Instead of using `require()` to load text files, consider using the [brfs](http://github.com/substack/brfs) transform. With brfs, you maintain parity with node by calling `fs.readFileSync()` but instead of doing synchronous IO as in node, brfs will inline the file contents into the bundle in-place so

```
var src = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/file.txt');
```

becomes

```
var src = "beep boop\n";
```

in the bundle output.

Just compile with `-t brfs`:

```
browserify -t brfs main.js > bundle.js
```

More discussion about why overloading `require()` too much is a bad idea: http://mattdesl.svbtle.com/browserify-vs-webpack

Comment: This works so long as the module in question is part of the top-level package tree--that is, NOT required from a package installed with `npm install`. But I'm not sure browserify's transform works across packages required by other installed packages.

Comment: This did the job for me, inserting shader code as strings into my three.js project.

Comment: I really feel like this is a horrible implementation, especially because one can't easily abstract this functionality and do something like: 

function getTemplate(path) { return fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/' + path, 'utf8'); }

Answer (score 9):

**stringify**:

https://github.com/JohnPostlethwait/stringify

Here's author example:

```
var bundle = browserify()
    .transform(stringify(['.hjs', '.html', '.whatever']))
    .add('my_app_main.js');
```

Answer (score 5):

If you really want to use `require()`, you may want to look at [partialify](https://github.com/bclinkinbeard/partialify):

`my.txt`:

```
Hello, world!
```

`index.js`:

```
alert( require( "my.txt" ) );
```

Where Browserify is configured:

```
var partialify = require( "partialify/custom" );
partialify.alsoAllow( "txt" );

bundle.add( "./index.js" );
bundle.transform( partialify );
```

Theoretically you will get a "Hello, world!" message in browser.
P.S. I haven't tried this myself.

**Edit**: note that this solution breaks NodeJS compatibility - it only works in browserified state, as NodeJS doesn't know how to require `.txt` files.

Comment: This worked for me. Just a note -- if you do this and you are also using babelify, you need to pass a whitelist of extensions to babelify so that it only processes files you want (.js, .jsx, etc.) and not text files or whatever other kinds of files you're requiring. You can do this by passing an --extensions flag to babelify.