# How to require Underscore templates with Browserify + Gulp

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js, gulp, browserify

I'm setting up a Backbone project with Browserify & Gulp and can't seem to figure out how to require Underscore templates (not Handlebars) in my modules. The closest I've come is using "node-underscorify" (at least seeing something and no errors), but it's not quite right..

**gulpfile.js**

```
var gulp       = require('gulp');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var source     = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var buffer     = require('vinyl-buffer');
var uglify     = require('gulp-uglify');
var gulpif     = require('gulp-if');
var sass       = require('gulp-sass');

var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'dev';

gulp.task( 'js', function() {

    var bundler = browserify({
        entries:   ['./dev/js/app.js'],
        paths:     ['./templates/'],                                
        transform: ['node-underscorify']
    });

    return bundler
        .bundle()
        .pipe( source( 'bundle.js') )
        .pipe( buffer() )
        .pipe( gulpif( env === 'prod', uglify() ) )
        .pipe( gulp.dest( './js/' ) );
});
```

**home.html**

```
<h3>Hello <%= name %></h3>
```

**HomeView.js** (compiled from CoffeeScript via a separate Gulp task)

```
(function() {
  var $, Backbone, _;
  $ = require('jquery');
  _ = require('underscore');
  Backbone = require('backbone');
  Backbone.$ = $;

  module.exports = Backbone.View.extend({

    template: require('home.html'),

    el: '#content',

    initialize: function() {
      console.log("home initialize");
      this.render();
    },

    render: function() {
      this.$el.html(this.template({
        name: 'Gulp!'
      }));
      return this;
    }

  });

}).call(this);
```

When I run the app and it hits HomeView, the browser displays what looks like raw JS of the module, including the uncompiled template (?)

```
module.exports = function(obj){ var __t,__p='',__j=Array.prototype.join,print=function(){__p+=__j.call(arguments,'');}; with(obj||{}){ __p+='
Hello '+ ((__t=( name ))==null?'':__t)+ '

\n\n'; } return __p; };
```

I tried applying the Underscore template function to the required file but that produces a JS error..

```
template: _.template( require('home.html') ),
```

Spent multiple hours perusing various blog posts, trying different solutions -- any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Found one solution based on this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17379891/how-to-require-text-files-with-browserify). Once installed `npm install brfs --save-dev`, need to require it in the view `var fs = require('fs');`, then the template can be loaded and compiled via `template: _.template(fs.readFileSync('./templates/home.html', 'utf8')),`. It'll do for now but I suppose it's not really "pre-compiling"? Happy to entertain better solutions!

Comment: That module looks like the compiled template code. Do you have any underscorify config in your `package.json`? What version of node-underscorify are you using?

Comment: I agree with @Ben -- that's the compiled template. In addition to node-underscorify, what version of browserify are you using? node-underscorify has a pretty "old" version of browserify as its dev dependency.

Comment: @Ben, JMM:  Thanks for the insights. The versions should be recent, just installed via `npm install`, as follows: `"browserify": "^8.1.1"` and `"node-underscorify": "0.0.14"` So, sounds like I'd need to use way older Browserify? If so, other good ways to do it?

Comment: I just upgraded to those versions in my project, and it still works. Although, I am registering the transform using `bundler.transform(underscorify.transform(...))` rather than the `transform` array.

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem.  I finally got this working by building off of the [example gulp recipe](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/fast-browserify-builds-with-watchify.md), but per Ben's comment, I explicitly call transform() on underscorify, instead of using the transform array.

I also choose to rename the bundled file along the way and output it in the same directory as the source.

Here's what my final working code looks like:

**gulpfile.js**

```
gulp = require("gulp");
browserify = require("browserify");
watchify = require("watchify");
underscorify = require("node-underscorify");
rename = require("gulp-rename");
source = require("vinyl-source-stream");  
gutil = require("gulp-util");

mainBundler = watchify(browserify("./js/main.js"));
mainBundler.transform(underscorify.transform());
gulp.task("watchify-main", bundleMain);
mainBundler.on("update", bundleMain);
mainBundler.on("log", gutil.log);

function bundleMain() {
return mainBundler.bundle()
    .on("error", gutil.log.bind(gutil, 'Browserify Error'))
    .pipe(source(".js/main.js"))
    .pipe(rename("main-bundle.js"))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./js/"));
};
```

home.html

```
 <h3>Hello <%= name %></h3>
```

main.js

```
template = require("./templates/home.html");

module.exports = Backbone.View.extend({
    template : template,

    el: "#content",

    initialize: function() {
        // initialize code
    },

    render: function() {
        // render code
    }
});
```